# Guidelines for choosing between image size and image compression for web use

Tags: html, image, image-processing

Here's the dilemma:

I'm working on making my web site using 'responsive design' The idea is that I want to have a single site that looks good on desktop and is usable on mobile.  The layout is liquid:  Almost all dimensions are expressed in percentages or ems.  The result of that made my site almost usable on an iPhone.  Some @media queries to use an alternate layout, viewport settings, and I have the start of a reasonable compromise.  (I don't want to maintain a separate mobile only site.)

In doing this I've found images that are way too large for their use.  E.g. An image sized to width 33% is over a megabyte.

**Guideline Question 1:**  On most desktop screens what is an acceptable ratio of image pixels to screen pixels.

Yes the computer will resize on the fly.  But resizing a 200 x 300 image to fill 600 x 900 spot will look soft with compression quality of 100.

**Guideline Question 2:**  At what compression  on typical images do artifacts become obvious.

**Guideline Question 3:**  How do quality decisions change as the visual angle of the image increases? The eventual use need consideration too.  An image that spans most of the page takes up a larger fraction of the viewing angle, and will get looked at more intently.

Now these are inter-related.  A large image, highly compressed, will have artifacts that are small and will become less obvious when the image is down sampled.

So I'm working with 3 variables:  Image use, pixel size, and compression.

So far: my thinking:

- There is little point in having more pixels in the image than the maximum expected use on the web page.  E.g. If I code for a 1200 pixel wide browser window, a 900 pixel wide content window, and a maximum in use image size of 800 pixels, then storing that image with a width of more than 800 pixels is foolish.  I suspect I can get away with considerably less than this.
- Compression quality of 75% is common, and a good starting point, but I bet I can crank this up somewhat higher with little detectable difference.
- Images that take a major part of the screen should be somewhat higher in quality.

My recourse at this point would be to write a script that would resize, and recompress in various ratios, and see what the difference is, but this is a long drawn out process.  Before I start that, I'm hoping that someone else has already done it and made their recommendations public.  That way I have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Notes while seeking an answer:

Good introduction here to the tradeoffs and options for other formats, along with some links to tools.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/img-compression/

If you are willing to run JavaScript on your browser, you can delay image loading; the JS picks the correct image to load based on the space on the device.  This is a good approach that I may eventually adopt, but does not directly address my question of the tradeoff.

http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/50092458307/images

Followup with more detail: http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/58244240772/imager-js